# PostgreSQL doesn't save full DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, devart

I have run into what seems like an error with either PostgreSQL or the Devart database connection library. The following is a simple test app I created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DateTimeOffsetTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                var e = new Ent() { CreatedOn = DateTimeOffset.Now };
                Console.WriteLine(e.CreatedOn.UtcDateTime.Ticks);
                context.Ents.Add(e);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                var ent = context.Ents.Single();

                Console.WriteLine(ent.CreatedOn.UtcDateTime.Ticks);
                Console.Read();

                context.Ents.Remove(ent);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect that the two lines being written to the console would be the same, but the second one always has a 0 in the last digit. Example:

[image: Test output]

Is this a precision issue with the way PostgreSQL is setup and if so, can I change that somehow? This test works fine if I am using SqlServer as my database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If CreatedOn is a PostgreSQL timestamp the precision is 1 microsecond. 1 tick is .1 microseconds.

Comment: I see, is there any way to increase the timestamp precision? I'm assuming not

Comment: You could store the ticks. 64 bits integer (bigint) is enough for your timestamps. If you don't like to use ticks in your program you could store the ticks as backing field then use a DateTime not mapped field

Comment: Good idea, I may have to do that. Thanks for the help